# How to enable Chrome load HTTPS without certificate?

Tags: google-chrome, https

Need to load http://localhost:3000 but chrome refuse.

I tried to press here, but no luck, it opens `keychain access`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found here: https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0XrnmGk1BRBc

Need: `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --ignore-certificate-errors &> /dev/null &`

---

even better: chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost

[Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate/31900210#31900210)